# Array Merge (Union)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have two array I need to merge, and using the Union (|) operator is PAINFULLY slow.. are there any other ways to accomplish an array merge?

Also, the arrays are filled with objects, not strings.

An Example of the objects within the array

```
#<Article 
 id: 1, 
 xml_document_id: 1, 
 source: "<article><domain>events.waikato.ac</domain><excerpt...", 
 created_at: "2010-02-11 01:32:46", 
 updated_at: "2010-02-11 01:41:28"
>
```

Where source is a short piece of XML.

**EDIT**

Sorry! By 'merge' I mean I need to not insert duplicates.

```
A => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B => [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
A.magic_merge(B) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Understanding that the integers are actually Article objects, and the Union operator appears to take *forever*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by merge? How will you handle object identity and differences in contents?

Comment: I dont know, I suppose what I'm looking for is a way to 'merge', and having a comparison operator to compare the objects come merge time.

Comment: Ryan: this is an interesting question, but I think you'll find you get more/better responses on this site if you vote for answers that are helpful and accept the best answer for each of your questions. This is the basic currency of Stack Overflow, and people are wary of helping someone when they see that the only answer they've accepted is their own.

Comment: Alex, I voted on multiple answers and accepted the solution..

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here's a script which benchmarks two merge techniques: using the pipe operator (`a1 | a2`), and using concatenate-and-uniq (`(a1 + a2).uniq`). Two additional benchmarks give the time of concatenate and uniq individually.

```
require 'benchmark'

a1 = []; a2 = []
[a1, a2].each do |a|
  1000000.times { a << rand(999999) }
end

puts "Merge with pipe:"
puts Benchmark.measure { a1 | a2 }

puts "Merge with concat and uniq:"
puts Benchmark.measure { (a1 + a2).uniq }

puts "Concat only:"
puts Benchmark.measure { a1 + a2 }

puts "Uniq only:"
b = a1 + a2
puts Benchmark.measure { b.uniq }
```

On my machine (Ubuntu Karmic, Ruby 1.8.7), I get output like this:

```
Merge with pipe:
  1.000000   0.030000   1.030000 (  1.020562)
Merge with concat and uniq:
  1.070000   0.000000   1.070000 (  1.071448)
Concat only:
  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.005888)
Uniq only:
  0.980000   0.000000   0.980000 (  0.981700)
```

Which shows that these two techniques are very similar in speed, and that `uniq` is the larger component of the operation. This makes sense intuitively, being O(n) (at best), whereas simple concatenation is O(1).

So, if you really want to speed this up, you need to look at how the `<=>` operator is implemented for the objects in your arrays. I believe that most of the time is being spent comparing objects to ensure inequality between any pair in the final array.

Comment: So the pipe operator will utilize the <=> operator if I just overload that? I'm not sure as though I'll be able to speed it up, as you can see that the object it is comparing is rather simple, but maybe it will speed it up if i just have it compare the source column instead of all 5 columns.. we shall see. Great answer though!

Answer (score 7):

Do you need the items to be in a specific order within the arrays? If not, you may want to check whether using `Set`s makes it faster.

**Update**

Adding to another answerer's code:

```
require "set"
require "benchmark"

a1 = []; a2 = []
[a1, a2].each do |a|
  1000000.times { a << rand(999999) }
end

s1, s2 = Set.new, Set.new

[s1, s2].each do |s|
  1000000.times { s << rand(999999) }
end

puts "Merge with pipe:"
puts Benchmark.measure { a1 | a2 }

puts "Merge with concat and uniq:"
puts Benchmark.measure { (a1 + a2).uniq }

puts "Concat only:"
puts Benchmark.measure { a1 + a2 }

puts "Uniq only:"
b = a1 + a2
puts Benchmark.measure { b.uniq }

puts "Using sets"
puts Benchmark.measure {s1 + s2}

puts "Starting with arrays, but using sets"
puts Benchmark.measure {s3, s4 = [a1, a2].map{|a| Set.new(a)} ; (s3 + s4)}
```

gives (for ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0])

```
Merge with pipe:
  1.320000   0.040000   1.360000 (  1.349563)
Merge with concat and uniq:
  1.480000   0.030000   1.510000 (  1.512295)
Concat only:
  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.019812)
Uniq only:
  1.460000   0.020000   1.480000 (  1.486857)
Using sets
  0.310000   0.010000   0.320000 (  0.321982)
Starting with arrays, but using sets
  2.340000   0.050000   2.390000 (  2.384066)
```

Suggests that sets may or may not be faster, depending on your circumstances (lots of merges or not many merges).

Comment: Order doesnt matter because i have to shuffle the array as well after its all merged - but the merge using sets is slower than the merge using concat which is the fastest method weve been able to come up with thus far. And I do have to use arrays because im merging an ActiveRecord dataset from the db, which is an array.. (I think)

Comment: If both arrays were originally database entities and speed is your concern, you may consider merging them on the database before constructing the objects. Can't really supply an example (or assess the feasibility of what I just wrote :-) ) without knowing schema details, but that may be worth researching.

Comment: Another thing: what you get from the database isn't really an Array, but an `ActiveRecord::Result` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html). As you can see in those docs, that class includes `Enumerable`, which is why it "quacks" like an Array most of the time (and also what gives it the convenient - and quite often implicitly called - `to_a` that converts it into an actual `Array`).

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Array#concat` method will likely be a lot faster, according to my initial benchmarks using Ruby 1.8.7:

```
require 'benchmark'

def reset_arrays!
  @array1 = []
  @array2 = []

  [@array1, @array2].each do |array|
    10000.times { array << ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex }
  end
end

reset_arrays! && puts(Benchmark.measure { @array1 | @array2 })
# => 0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.026677)

reset_arrays! && puts(Benchmark.measure { @array1.concat(@array2) })
# => 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000122)
```

Comment: What does concat do with duplicates?

Comment: It keeps them, but you could do `Array#uniq` afterwards to get rid of dups.

Comment: Ok, I will need to test concat vs + as well to see which is faster

Comment: The heaviest operation is the `uniq` command, which `|` does, hence why `concat` appears to be so much faster. Appending an Array is fast. Removing duplicates is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if this is any faster

```
a = [1,2,3,3,2]
b = [1,2,3,4,3,2,5,7]
(a+b).uniq
```