# Coalescing the results of two find_bys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code that obtains the results of two finds:

results1 = firstModel.find_by_id(id1)

results2 = secondModel.find_by_id(id2)

allResults = results1 & results2  # merge the results, removing duplicates

# I believe find_by returns an array, but, a little out of desperation, I've also tried, allResults = results1.merge(results2)

However, with both, I get 'undefined method' ('&' or 'merge', respectively)

I'd appreciate some hints as to why, thanks.

Comment: Why are you expecting duplicates if these are two separate models?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242042/array-merge-union

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe find_by returns an array, but, a little out of desperation, I've also tried, allResults = results1.merge(results2)
>
> However, with both, I get 'undefined method' ('&' or 'merge', respectively)

`find_by_id` will return a single object and not a collection.

To return collections, you can do something like this:

```
MyModel.find_all_by_name("hello world")
```

And then you can do a merge on this.

Comment: Thanks everyone - all helpful, and Jits response gave me the insight I needed.

Answer (score 2):

With Rails 3, you can do something like this:

```
firstModel.where(:id => id1) | secondModel.where(:id => id2)
# => [#<FirstModel id: 1, ....>, #<SecondModel id: 1, ....>]
```

Answer (score 1):

If results1 and results2 are arrays then:

```
allResults = (results1 + results2).uniq
```

Docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html