# Ruby code to merge two arrays not working

Tags: ruby

```
nums1 = Array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
nums2 = Array[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def mergeArrays (ar1, ar2)
   result = (ar1 << ar2).flatten!

   require 'pp'
   pp %w(result)
end
```

As simple as this. I am trying to merge these two arrays and display the result. I am also brand-brand new to Ruby. This is the first function I am writing in this language. Trying to learn here. Also how can I remove the duplicates?

Comment: @David's answer may well be a good candidate to be selected, but why in the world would you make your selection so quickly? Doing so may discourage other answers and is perhaps not especially considerate to those (not me) still preparing their answers. There's no rush to award the greenie. Many here wait a minimum of a couple of hours before making a selection.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the comment. I usually close my topics as soon as I am done with the problem. Never thought about this. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help if you give example inputs and outputs so we know exactly what you want.  When you use the word "merge", I think you actually just want to add the arrays together:

```
ar1 = [1, 2, 3]
ar2 = [3, 4, 5]
ar3 = ar1 + ar2   # => [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now if you want to remove duplicates, use [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
ar4 = ar3.uniq    # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

There is no need to write a method to do any of this since the Ruby Array class already supports it.  You should skim through the [documentation of the Array class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) to learn more things you can do with arrays.

Comment: how can I print the result?

Comment: You can use `puts ar4` or `p ar4`.  The latter is a shortcut for `puts ar4.inspect`.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean 'not working'?

Similar questions have been asked here:
[Array Merge (Union)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242042/array-merge-union)

You have two options: the pipe operator `(a1 | a2)` or concatenate-and-uniq `((a1 + a2).uniq)`.

Also be careful about using `<<`, this will **modify** the original variable, concatenating ar2 onto the end of the original ar1.

```
nums1 = Array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
nums2 = Array[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
result = (nums1<< nums2).flatten!

nums1
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
nums2 
=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
result
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Additionally- just another Ruby tip, you do not need the destructive [flatten!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21) with `!` versus the regular [flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten). The regular `flatten` method will return a new Array, which you assign to `result` in your case. `flatten!` will flatten `self` in place, altering whatever Array it's called upon, rather than returning a new array.

Answer (score 1):

```
nums1 = Array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
nums2 = Array[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

p nums1.concat(nums2).uniq
```

Comment: Ruman is "brand new to Ruby", so it would be helpful to at least point to where docs for [Array#concat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) and [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) can be found, show the intermediate array `nums1` (not `num1`) and show what is printed using [Kernel#p](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p). It should also be noted that this modifies `nums1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge Arrays using `'+'` operator and you can ignore the duplicated values using `.uniq`

```
>> nums1 = Array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> nums2 = Array[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>> def mergeArrays (nums1, nums2)
>> result = (nums1 + nums2).uniq
>> end
=> :mergeArrays

>> mergeArrays(nums1,nums2)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```